# Как из таблицы формата excel создать json файл в нужном виде

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Имеется таблица [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как из нее создать json-файл следующего вида

```
{
    'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0':
        [{'Название': 'Акита-ину', 'Страна': 'Япония'},
         {'Название': 'Басенджи', 'Страна': 'Центральная Африка'},
         {'Название': 'Пекинес', 'Страна': 'Китай'}],
    'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0':
        [{'Название': 'Бурмилла', 'Страна': 'Великобритания'},
         {'Название': 'Мэнкс', 'Страна': 'Великобритания'},
         {'Название': 'Рагамаффин', 'Страна': 'США'}],
}
```

Сначала я конвертирую эту таблицу в датафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('animals.xlsx')
```

и нашла регулярку, которая удаляет ссылки из датафрейма, но мне нужно их как-то сохранять, чтоб сделать ключами словаря

```
df['Название'] = df['Название'].replace(r'http\S+', '', regex=True)
```